# Where do those requests comes from for the site that I haven't released to public?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-sql

I started using Php runtime for hosting my wordpress blog on Google app engine.

I have a bit of confusions over the "Overview" chart that I am seeing.

According to "Running Wordpress guide", the cron job is getting triggered every 2 hours. But I haven't finished the migrations yet so I removed that scheduler to save money. Nobody knows my Google App engine URL.

As you can see "APIs" chart, there is no more requests.

But in "App engine" chart, "Cloud SQL" chart and "Read/Write operations" chart, you can still see some activities that happens regularly. Is there any scheduler or back-end job (except the 2 hours cron job that I disabled already) that makes those requests?

Google costs me around USD 1.* after setting up about four days ago.

[image]

Comment: Michael, if you look under 'cron jobs' in your app engine app's admin console, is a cron job (e.g.'/wp-cron.php') still listed there?

Comment: I will check the logs.. cron.php is stil there but I delete the line for scheduler. I will try deleting the whole file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the App Engine logs say?

Comment: I will search how to check the log.. Thanks!